# API design for converting between Rationals and Reals

Tags: java, design-patterns, stl, factory-pattern

I have a design patterns question:- Let's say I have to design a Math library that has the following classes: Real and Rational.

What is the best design pattern to follow to add the following methods to the library:

- approximate real as rational
- convert rational to real
- simplify a rational number
- Mediant of a rational number

I can see a couple of approaches.

Approach-1:

- Add real.toRational()/Rational.fromReal(), rational.toReal(), rational.simplify(), rational.mediant()

Approach-2:

- Add them as static factor methods to a class NumberFactory like: Operations.real2Rational(), Operations.rational2Real(), Operational.simplifyRational(), Operations.mediant()

What are the Pros/Cons of each approach? My take is as follows:-

Approach-1 Pros:

- method names are simpler and concise.
- Better OO encapsulation

Approach-1 Cons:

- The Classes Real and Rational are now bloated with all these Converter and Utility methods

Approach-2 Pros:

- The classes Real and Rational remain short and clean and their dependency on other classes is minimized.
- Easy to remember: The library user will know fore sure that all the methods are in a single class called NumberFactory

Approach-2 Cons:

- Seems to be less OO'ish.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used these terms in many many years so perhaps I'm misremembering but aren't all `Rational` numbers `Real`?.  In that case `Rational` *is A* `Real` so `Rational` should be a subclass of `Real`.

Therefore your first approach is probably best:

For simplicity let's just pretend `Real` wraps a `double` of its value.

```
public class Real{

  private final double value;

  public double getValue(){
      return value;
  }

}
```

The `Rational` class has the more interesting methods.  Since its a subclass of `Real` it will still have the `getValue()` method which returns a double so you don't need a `toReal()` converter method anymore.

Since Rational numbers can be expressed as a fraction should also store the numerator and denominator along with getters.

```
public class Rational extends Real{
     private final long numerator,denominator;

     ....
     public long getNumerator(){ ..}

     public long getDenominator(){ ..}

}
```

Simplify is just modifying the numerator and denominator (but the same real value). Good API should use immutable objects and mutator methods should return new instances so we can add our simplify method like this:

```
public Rational extends Real{

       ...

   public Rational simplify(){
      //check if we are already simplified
      //if so return this
      if(alreadySimplified()){
           return this;
      }
      return new Rational(value, reducedNum, reducedDenom);


   }
}
```

Mediant can either be a method in Rational that takes a second `Rational` as a parameter or a method in a static utility class that takes 2 `Rational`s.  I'll leave that up to you but either way, you should return new instances instead of mutated already existing values.

The most interesting part of the API design is how to convert a `Real` into a `Rational`?  should there be a method that makes an approximate `Rational` if the `Real` isn't already `Rational`?  to the method instead throw an Exception?  How would you know if your `Real` instance is actually a `Rational` subclass?  (perhaps an `isRational()` method?  or use instanceof check?  I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I think the right way to put it is - A Rational can be converted to a Real, but no, A Rational is not a Real. They are different things. This is akin to the classic example of Rectangle vs. Square where the natural inclination might be to say Square extends Rectangle but that wouldn't make sense from an OO standpoint because then you would have methods like getWidth() and getHeight() on a Square class which don't make sense.

Comment: @ajay I disagree; a Square IS a Rectangle.  getWidth() and getHeight() still make sense for square.  It's just that Square is the special case where getWidth() and getHeight() return the same value.

Comment: An apparent mathematical is-a relation is not always a good reason for using subclassing.  If the classes are immutable, you might get away with this, but it doesn't mean it's good design.

Comment: dkatzel: you mix the notions of being a subset (yes, rationals are a subset of reals) and is-relationship (no, a rational is **not** a real). The same with squares and rectangles. Try search the internet for circle-ellipse problem (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) for deeper insight.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Java API and get inspiration there.
Your classes `Rational` and `Real` may extend the `Number` class in an analogous way as `Integer` and `Double` do. It's a very similar case of relationship.